# Creating test app through facebook ads account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

My question is about Facebook Ads API's March 4 breaking changes regarding the new campaign structure.

I do not have a test account nor a test app yet. I would like to test whether my code supports all the March 4 breaking changes. I have neither a test account nor a test app. I have requested a test account through email (this was suggested in the change [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/new-campaign-structure-faq)). I will later whitelist the account for accessing the structure changes.

To get the test app, do I have to use only the test account (creating an app requires a developer account) or can I create the test app directly by using my production facebook ads account?

Also, the page to apply for test ads app is the same as getting a normal ads app. [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/new-campaign-structure-faq) suggests that I add "test" to my name. Is this all I have to do or is there something more? The link for helping set up app in the [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/new-campaign-structure-faq) doesn't seem to point to the right place and doesn't help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1-To get a test app all u need is to be a developer. Once the app is created u can use it with a test/production account.
2-test and production apps can be created from the same place. Just put "test" in the app name.